# md-select options doesn't work with md-menu?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm having an issue with md-options being hidden behind an md-menu - I'm using the md-select in a 'sub menu' (see image below):

[image: md-select options behind md-menu]

It was asked about [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6837) and the answer was given that md-select was not supported inside of an md-menu yet, but I wonder if anyone has found a workaround? In my case, I have a dropdown of different checkboxes/selection options in each sub menu so using something like md-chips would really be a pivot from what I'm trying to accomplish.

HTML

```
<md-menu>
      <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">open menu</md-button>
      <md-menu-content>
        <md-menu-item>
          <md-menu>
            <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">First ></md-button>
            <md-menu-content>
              <md-menu-item>
                option 1
               </md-menu-item>
               <md-menu-item>
                option 2
               </md-menu-item>
               <md-menu-item>
                option 3
               </md-menu-item>
                        </md-menu-content>
          </md-menu>
        </md-menu-item>

        <md-menu-item>
          <md-menu>
            <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">Second ></md-button>
            <md-menu-content>
              <md-input-container>
                <md-select placeholder="Select an option..." ng-model="optionChosen">
                  <md-option ng-repeat="option in options" ng-value="option">
                                            {{option}}
                                        </md-option>
                </md-select>
              </md-input-container>
            </md-menu-content>
          </md-menu>
        </md-menu-item>
      </md-menu-content>
    </md-menu>
```

JavaScript

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = [
    'option one',
    'option two',
    'options three'
  ];

  $scope.optionChosen = null;
});
```

Working Code: [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/P6WqChEjI6aPbhJ2rK25)

Comment: Can you go to RedWingCenter.com and look at the Team Pages item in the hamburger menu and tell me if that's an acceptable solution? If so, I'll detail how it's done.

Comment: @MikeFeltman Thanks for pointing that out, but my submenu could have 15+ options so something like that wouldn't be suitable.

Comment: @WilliamHampshire - did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: @santosh I did not. Give it an upvote if you've had the same problem / think it's a good question though! Others will be more likely to look into it

Comment: did you find the solution for this? T_T